# Set session time out limit for magento frontend

Tags: magento

I am trying to set session time out limit to 30 minutes in magento but it is not expiring in 30 minutes. I went to **System->Configuration->Web->Session Cookie management** and set 1800 value for the field `Cookie Life time` but still it is not expiring the session in specified time out limit. I don't know what is wrong with Magento frontend session.

Am I setting the limit at right place?
Is there any other setting in magento backend to set the frontend session time out limit.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found out what I was missing.

I was setting the cookie life time for default configuration but it did not work.

But this also needs to set the time out in website and store configuration scope.

After setting the time for these scopes it worked.

Comment: Hi, I did the samething for front end cookie lifetime value for 300 seconds for my one of the store view. But it's not working and the .frontend cookie expiry date is taking "session". Am i did any wrong?

Comment: Just select your store view in the drop down at the top left. Thats what he is talking about.

Answer (score 27):

This can also be achieved from the admin panel without touching a single line of code.

Go to **System->Configuration->Advanced->Admin->Security** and set the session lifetime to how many seconds you wish.  I always set it to one day (86400 seconds) on my development environment.

[image]

**System->Configuration->Web->Session Cookie management** is for setting the timeout for normal users, signing into their profile & not the admin panel.

Comment: Hi, I did the samething for front end cookie lifetime value for 300 seconds for my one of the store view. But it's not working and the .frontend cookie expiry date is taking "session". Am i did any wrong?

Answer (score 12):

I had this issue with the Magento admin session . The crux of the problem is that Magento's cookies obey PHP's `session.gc_maxlifetime` parameter. If you adjust that in your htaccess like the following, you should have better luck:

```
php_value session.gc_maxlifetime 86400
```

Hope that helps!

Thanks,
Joe

Comment: Thanks for your interest Joseph. But the actual problem is the session is never expiring and I want to set it to expire in 30 minutes. Even session.gc_maxlifetime is set to default 1440.

Comment: How does "Session Cookie Management" affect this? (see Web section of configuration)

Comment: Joe, Do you have any Idea? When I go and set time limit for admin session. It is working for admin area. But no luck for frontend.

Comment: Hi Joe, After doing a lot of stuff,exercise I got What I was doing wrong. I am Just Posting as an answer.

Comment: HEy Joseph, Your link goes to a irrelevant page.

Comment: Thanks Mike, the URL was no longer functional, just removed it.

Comment: This is 24h though,,,,