# Different lifetime for different session value in Magento

Tags: magento

I use core session to store the frequently accessed data on Product Page. I've set the session cookie lifetime 0 which means it's good until browser is closed.

However, I need a specific value to be valid for 5 minutes only. How can I do that?

```
$session = Mage::getSingleton('core/session');
$session->setData('SomeValue',$value);
```

Is there a way where I can limit the SomeValue session data for 5 minutes while the other sessions data good until browser is closed?

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4022952/set-session-time-out-limit-for-magento-frontend

Comment: Thanks, but it's not what I need. I need different lifetime for different session value.